# Replacing a substring will only work in the last letter? why?

Tags: c#, replace, stringbuilder

I'm new to programming so I wasn't really sure how to title this, but I'm trying to replace letters in a string builder object by comparing it to a strings Substrings but it will only work with the last letter, why? And how do I replace the middle letters in the same fashion?

```
string S = "Hello";
StringBuilder sB = new StringBuilder("*****");
Console.WriteLine(sB);

string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (userInput == S.Substring(i))
    {
        sB.Remove(i, 1);
        sB.Insert(i, userInput);
        Console.WriteLine(sB);
    }
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The [`string.Substring(int)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx) returns the *whole substring* starting at the indicated character index, not just one character.

For retrieving the ith caracter of `S`, use `S[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

Substring with only 1 parameter will take everything from that position to the end of the string ("Hello".Substring(1) would be "ello"). To take only one letter you need to provide a second parameter for the length ("Hello".Substring(1,1) would be "e").

```
            if (userInput.Substring(i, 1) == S.Substring(i, 1))
            {
                sB.Remove(i, 1);
                sB.Insert(i, userInput.Substring(i, 1));
                Console.WriteLine(sB);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in using `String.Contains(string comparison)` to simply see if a string is within another.  Also, `String.Replace(string target, string replacement)` to replace variable-length strings rather than looping through characters.